# _ is not defined - NodeJS + UnderscoreJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, npm, underscore.js

Trying to use Underscore JS in a Node.JS project. Really stumped why it is not working. Note: **This works if I simply use the CDN for underscore.** However I'd really like to know why I am unable to get this to work using NPM.

**I am getting this error:**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined
```

Installed with: `npm install underscore --save`

Within the app.js file & Index files have tried both of these:

```
var _ = require('underscore')._
```

and

```
var underscore = require('underscore');
```

Even tried requiring it within the page render:

```
res.render("dashboard", {currentUser: req.user, underscore : underscore});
```

This is the test I'm using:

```
<script> 
var tacos = ['beef', 'chicken', 'soft', 'hard', 'With nacho cheese']
 _.shuffle([tacos]);
 console.log(_.shuffle(tacos)); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use like this way :

```
var _ = require('underscore')
```

or define globally:

```
 global._ = require('underscore')
```

example use :

```
_.map([1, 2, 3], function(num){ return num * 3; });
```

if you are using underscore js frontend side then CDN link or download and put in /public/js folder

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.9.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script> 
 var tacos = ['beef', 'chicken', 'soft', 'hard', 'With nacho cheese'];
 var shuffled =_.shuffle(tacos);
 console.log(shuffled); 
</script>
```

Comment: No such luck :(

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi , underscore is library , no need to pass to view as varialble

Comment: Took it out of the render - still does not seem to be working *confused face*

Comment: Thank you - Still curious why I cannot use NPM?

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi , please upvote and accept my answer if is useful to you :)

Comment: @AndrewLeonardi , use global._ = require('underscore') so you can use it in EJS file as well , without adding CDN link

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have tried all except the obvious one!

```
var _ = require('underscore')
```

Comment: Tried that one too :D No luck

Comment: It does work so you'll have to be more detailed about where it's not working in your code https://repl.it/@DominicTobias/HummingAmusedProperty